Problem with Vercel and React-Three-Fiber
Console error & Code with Folder distribution
I'm working with React-Three-Fiber.
In the localhost works good but when I do the deploy, the website principal screen works ok but when I do click on the 'Order' (is the site where is the 3D object) screen the web crash.
This is the web link: https://rocketfin.vercel.app/
The files are in the Public folder... I think Vercel doesn't want to work with the Public folder
How can I solve it?
I tryied move the files from the 'Public' to another folder inside 'src' but I think Three-Fiber cant work with files inside the 'src' folder

I solved it adding this line to vite.config.js:
publicDir: 'Public',

The code look like this now:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  publicDir: 'Public',
})

